# How to deploy activiti workflow other than activiti explorer and access it from external webapp

Tags: java, activiti

I have developed a simple workflow from one of the example [Get IP Country](http://www-inf.it-sudparis.eu/SIMBAD/courses/doku.php?id=teaching_assistant:workflow:activiti_soap#dokuwiki__top). I deployed it on activiti-explorer and it works fine. Now I want to deploy it somewhere else other than activiti-explorer and want to access it from my web app. How can I achieve it? Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Do you have additional artifacts that you use in your app, but are not part of the flow itself ? JARs, containing extra activity logic are typically the case. I such scenarios, you flow and app actually a single app, so it makes more sense to deploy in a single package (war/ear/fat jar..)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by deploying activiti-rest provided by Activiti on my server and used following rest call using Postman to deploy my workflow .bpmn file.

**Method** :        POST

**Request URL** :   http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/deployments

**Headers**:

**Header Name** :   *Authorization* **Header Value :    Username**: *kermit*    &   **Password**:   *kermit*

**Header Name** :   *Content-Type*  **Header Value** :  *multipart/form-data*

**Body**:

**Body content type** : *multipart/form-data*

**File name** :     *Some file name & choose .bpmn file*

Once we make a POST call along with above information, our workflow will be deployed and we will receive below JSON response:

```
{
"id": "2501",
"name": "ApplyLeave.bpmn",
"deploymentTime": "2018-02-16T18:15:04.277+05:30",
"category": null,
"url": "http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/deployments/2501",
"tenantId": ""
}
```